# Preventing ViewController From Shifting Back to Previous

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have a simple sample iOS app with two view controllers (`UIViewController`) as follows.

```
//HomeViewController
import UIKit

class HomeViewController: UIViewController {
    // MARK: - IBAction
    @IBAction func goSecondTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        if let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondNavigator") as? UINavigationController {
            if let viewController = controller.topViewController as? SecondViewController {
                self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    // MARK: - Life cycle
    override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}

//SecondViewController
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {
    // MARK: - Life cycle
    override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

[image]

So I just want to shift to SecondViewController when I tap the button (Go to Second).  The problem is that I can go back to HomeViewController without tapping the Back button at the top-left corner if I just swipe the second view from left to right with my finger.  Is there any way of preventing that?  I want to go back HomeViewController only when I tap Back.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you ever tried disable the `interactivePopGestureRecognizer`?

```swift
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled = false
}
```